# How do I run teardown code in a powershell script under all exit conditions?

Tags: powershell

The issue is the powershell `trap` keyword. In Unix/Linux/FreeBSD the [trap command](https://ss64.com/bash/trap.html#:%7E:text=Execute%20a%20command%20when%20the%20shell%20receives%20a,executed%20when%20the%20shell%20receives%20signal%20%28s%29%20sigspec.) can capture signals, including the signal to exit or kill the script itself that a user or IDE might send to the script via `CTRL-C`, `htop`, `kill`, etc.

In powershell, the `trap` keyword is only for catching errors.  So the trap command seems to be syntactical sugar for a try-catch-finally block. Whereas in regular shell, the `trap` keyword is an auto-cleaning, more surgical version of Powershell's [Register-EngineEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-engineevent?view=powershell-7.3) command.

The `Register-EngineEvent` command only allows global powershell events to trigger exit code.  Further, it must be cleaned in some meta scope -- perhaps with the incomplete try-catch-finally trap. This means that an unstable state can be reached for a script that registers engine events or other event actions in the body of the script.

The result is that interaction with events is needlessly painful. For example, a script that registers an indication event in the body and unregisters in the teardown:

```
trap {
  Unregister-Event ...
}
try {
  Register-CimIndicationEvent ...
}
finally {
  Unregister-Event ...
}
```

Can be broken or cause subsequent instances to yield error messages with a manual halt or kill signal by dangling registrations.

If I register the teardown code with the `Register-EngineEvent` under one of two available signals, `[Powershell.Exiting, Powershell.OnIdle]`, an adjacent powershell script, user, or myself can suddenly break my program by generating an unrelated `Powershell.Exiting` event.

If instead I control the `Register-EngineEvent` from an external scope s.t. it attaches to the particular script, I recreate the same problem: I still must tear down the `EngineEvent` in the `try...catch...finally` structure, which is not guaranteed to run the `finally` component under all normal runtime conditions.

There must be a way out of this *trap* in powershell?

Comment: In powershell 7.3 they added a `clean` block. This may be the solution you're looking for. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: The discussion in [GitHub issue #8000](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8000) may help.